# What does "Got to own your own, you have to got to own your own" mean (song lyric)?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand what "Got to own your own, you have to got to own your own" means, it could interpreted as something you can use like a motivational phrase or is translated literally like "you have to be on command of yourself"?

Comment: It would be very very hard to say without knowing the full context. Please provide the surrounding lyrics as well as the name of the song and the artist who sings it. A youtube link to a recording of the song would be helpful as well, especially if you share a link to the exact time in the song where you hear the lyric (there is an option for this if you click the "share" button under the youtube video).

Comment: Oh I see, here is the song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHTA-c4VX10 and the lyrics: https://www.musixmatch.com/es/letras/Yazmin-Lacey-2/Own-Your-Own Thank you so much for replaying

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of scenarios where you could legitimately say "own your own", due to the fact that there are multiple meanings of the word 'own'. For example, it is fairly common to say "I own my own home", in which the first use of the word is a verb for ownership, and the second instance works as a determiner to indicate whose home it is.

Without the full lyrics of your song I can't be overly specific about the meaning but it's pretty clear your quotation is the same format as my example, using the word firstly as a verb and then as a determiner. "Own", in the sense of ownership, has a common modern usage which means to accept or embrace some aspect of your life. My assumption, without further context, would be that "got to own your own" means you should accept or embrace who you are, or accept what you have and enjoy / appreciate it.

Comment: Or that there's some material object that's referenced in the surrounding context, such that the subject of what "own your own [thing]" is supposed to be obvious.