# What "Own your own" means?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand what "Got to own your own, you have to got to own your own" means, it could interpreted as something you can use like a motivational phrase or is translated literally like "you have to be on command of yourself"?

This is from the lyrics of the song of Yazmin Lacey - Own Your Own

Comment: It's not a common idiom, and song lyrics are often deliberately vague to resonate as broadly as possible…. I don't see it as a "Be your own boss" motivational, rather a warning to nurture and protect a safe retreat within yourself. "Own your own" suggest multiple interpretations: discovering education and knowledge to 'live free', preserving cultural history and truth however painful or oppressive, surviving the 'grind' of life, and especially protecting your personal mental health.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Im trying to figure out what this verse means](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/289452/im-trying-to-figure-out-what-this-verse-means) — if your original question has not received enough traffic, you can edit it (as I requested) to include more information, which will bring it to the top of the question queue, or (when you have enough reputation) assign a bounty to it. You should not post a new question asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple meanings of the word 'own'. It can be a verb, a pronoun, and a determiner, so it isn't surprising it could be used more than once in a statement. For example, it is fairly common to say "I *own* my *own* home", in which the first use of the word is a *verb* for *ownership*, and the second instance works as a *determiner* to indicate whose home it is (obviously, it is quite common to own a property that somebody else lives in, and to live in a property that you do not own).

Without the full lyrics of your song I can't be overly specific about the meaning but it's pretty clear your quotation is using the word firstly as a verb meaning *to take ownership of*, and then as a pronoun referring to *what is yours*. "Own", in the sense of ownership, has a common modern usage which means to *gain control of* something, particularly with reference to your life. My assumption, without further context, would be that "got to own your own" means you should *take control of* what is already yours - perhaps *your life*.